# Scheduling startup (booting) of a Azure VM

Tags: azure, schedule, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows based VM on Azure Cloud. Using the Portal on portal.azure.com I can start/stop the machine.

Is there a way to create a schedule in Azure so that the VM is started (booting) on a specific date/time / schedule? So that the VM's state is changed from Stopped (deallocated) to Running when it is scheduled to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule any operations with Azure Automation.

[This article](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/01/using-azure-automation-to-run-vms-during-office-hours-only/) describes how to run Azure VMs during office hours.